# how to create a table made of two same tables with different content ?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table: `table1`, `table2`. I need to mix them and then `create` a new table.

Here is my example:

```
// table1:
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------|------+
| 111  |  222 |
| 333  |  444 |
+------+------+

// table2:
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------|------+
| 555  |  666 |
| 777  |  888 |
+------+------+
```

So, I need something like this:

```
// new_table:
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------|------+
| 111  |  222 |
| 333  |  444 |
| 555  |  666 |
| 777  |  888 |
+------+------+
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union`

```
create table table3 as
    select col1, col2 from table1
    union all
    select col1, col2 from table2
```

Comment: you did not use of `create` for creating a new table ?

Comment: You are welcome. But no, I don't communicate outside this site.

Comment: I have a question about `TRIGGER` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920600/how-to-create-a-update-trigger-for-increase-decrease-1-number-to-total-votes-num) (part of Edit). I think you can solve it, please take a look at it, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the same items, you can

```
create table new_table as
    select col1, col2 from table1
    union
    select col1, col2 from table2
```