# Create or alter trigger if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to determine withing if If I should create or alter and trigger. My Code is below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Sales.bonus_reminder', N'TR') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    AFTER INSERT
    AS RAISERROR ('Notify Compensation', 16, 10);
else
    CREATE TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS RAISERROR ('Notify Compensation', 16, 10);
```

The errors I'm getting are :

- Incorrect syntax near else
- Create trigger should be the only
  statement in batch.

How this code should look like?

Comment: Have a look at this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/38684064-c9bd-4fc2-8c8c-7feb98b0252d/creating-a-trigger-inside-a-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want to the *create trigger* statement as dynamic SQL, then you can do something like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Sales.bonus_reminder', N'TR') IS NOT NULL
    exec sp_executesql N'DROP TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder';
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS RAISERROR ('Notify Compensation', 16, 10);
```

Comment: I thought about droping and recreating but isn't better to alter instead of recreate? or this doesn't matter?

Comment: @szpic . . . An `alter` would normally be better.  For instance, when you drop a trigger and recreate it, there is a gap of time when the data could be modified and there is no trigger.  In practice, though, I use triggers quite sparingly.  Because they are part of "maintenance mode" on any system, I'm not worried about changes to the data.

Comment: @Sajad . . . Of course.  Triggers are used like that all the time to maintain summary tables.

Comment: I think like you, but seems wrong. take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920600/how-to-create-a-update-trigger-for-increase-decrease-1-number-to-total-votes-num) (part of Edit). no one does not answer me :( !

Answer (score 7):

Using [this articular](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4640/new-create-or-alter-statement-in-sql-server-2016-sp1/) as my source of truth. here is the short answer.

As of `SQL Server 2016 sp1` you can use `create or alter` statements instead of other drop and create methods (my personal fav till this) on some of the database objects (`stored procedures`/`functions`/`triggers`/`views`).

so your script could look like

```
create or alter TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS RAISERROR ('Notify Compensation', 16, 10)
```

Comment: Here's better authority to cite: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: they are the greater authority but that person who wrote the articular i ref is the ref i used and they deserve the credit ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use Dynamic SQL

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Sales.bonus_reminder', N'TR') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC('
    ALTER TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    AFTER INSERT
    AS RAISERROR (''Notify Compensation'', 16, 10)'
    );
else
    EXEC('
    CREATE TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder
    ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory
    WITH ENCRYPTION
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
    AS RAISERROR (''Notify Compensation'', 16, 10)'
    );
```